# How can I train a Keras LSTM model with multiple features to only predict on one variable, while also having different timestep shapes for X and Y

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, time-series

I am trying to train a time series Keras LSTM model where my training data has shape **(64, 70, 2)** and I would like the output shape to be **(64, 35, 1)**. The reasoning for this is that I am trying to have the same batch size across both my X and Y; however, for every 70 timepoints in my training data I want the output y to show the next 35 values (Maybe this is the wrong way to do this, and could be where my issue is stemming from). The reason for this is because I do not necessarily want timepoints 0-35 to be used to predict timepoints 35-70, instead I want timepoints 0-70 to predict 71-105.

My input data in this case has 2 features (columns), and I am training to train on both features, but I am only trying to predict one of the two features, therefore the training data having 2 in the shape, and the output having 1.

I have set up my LSTM in the following way

```
inputs_1_mae = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, train_window, data.shape[1]))
    lstm_1_mae = LSTM(10, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs_1_mae)
    lstm_2_mae = LSTM(10, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(lstm_1_mae)

    output_1_mae = Dense(units=1)(lstm_2_mae)

    regressor_mae = Model(inputs=inputs_1_mae, outputs=output_1_mae)

    regressor_mae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

However, this results in the error `ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 70 and 35 for '{{node mean_absolute_error/sub}} = Sub[T=DT_FLOAT](mean_absolute_error/remove_squeezable_dimensions/Squeeze, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [64,70], [64,35].`

After following a stackoverflow recommendation (can't find link): I added a flatten to the layers, like below, which allowed it to train the LSTM.

```
inputs_1_mae = Input(batch_shape=(batch_size, train_window, data.shape[1]))
    lstm_1_mae = LSTM(10, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(inputs_1_mae)
    lstm_2_mae = LSTM(10, stateful=True, return_sequences=True)(lstm_1_mae)

    flatten = Flatten()(lstm_2_mae)
    output_1_mae = Dense(units=1)(flatten)

    regressor_mae = Model(inputs=inputs_1_mae, outputs=output_1_mae)

    regressor_mae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

However, now once I go to perform a prediction on it using an X_test of shape (2816, 70, 2) using the code `predicted_values = regressor_mae.predict(X_test, batch_size=batch_size)`

I get a full list of NaN values. Therefore I don't think the Flattening will get me the result I am looking for.

Tried adding a flat layer to the Keras architecture.